# ajax call does not work in angular js

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the scenario as follow:

I have a text box and button and whenever I add sth in textbox I want to add the text in the table my code is as follow:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Service', function() {
    var typesHash = [ {
        id :1,
        name : 'lemon',
        price : 100,
        unit : 2.5
    }, {
        id : 2,
        name : 'meat',
        price : 200,
        unit : 3.3
    } ];

    var localId = 3;

    var service = {
        addTable : addTable,
        getData : getData,


    };
    return service;
    function addTable(name) {
        typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:100,unit:1});
    }
    function getData() {
        return typesHash;
    }
});
app.controller('table', function(Service) {
    //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
    this.typesHash = Service.getData();
    //get the addtable function from factory 
    this.addTable = Service.addTable;
});
```

and the plnkr is as follow:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBQqCZEomAsKXxLYpHWH?p=preview)

Now as you can see I add whatever inside the text in the table and everything works fine but now I want to add whatever inside the textbox and also I want to get some information from the servlet and add those to the table as well. so for that I use ajax call as follow:

```
function addTable(name) {
        typesHash.push({id:localId++, name:name, price:100,unit:1});
        var responsePromise = $http.get("http://localhost:8080/purchase/AddInfo");
             responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    typesHash.push( {id:data.id,name : data.name, price : data.price,unit:2.5 });
                });
    }
```

but when I use that I get he following error:

ReferenceError: $http is not defined

can anyone help? (just a quick note: this code is smaller version of my real code and I purposely used factory since I need it)

Comment: You would need to inject `$http` inorder to use it. `app.factory('Service', function($http) {` or `app.factory('Service', ['$http', function($http) {` .Marking for closure for typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside of your controller attr your should insert an $http argument:

```
app.controller('CTRL1', function($scope, $http){
    //Now your can use $http methods
})
```

or insert $http argument in your service decleration if you are using $http request methods from inside of your service